Seating Arrangement
My Department has had a move around after me working there for 15 months. I have always sat with my back to a wall and facing anyone that comes towards me this is because of the nature of work HR/Finance. My new desk is in a cluster of 4 so they can bounce ideas off each other even though they are not in the office everyday. At this present time they come in once a week I am there 5 days a week.
I sat in my new seat and triggered bad memories from my past and instantly became upset. I approached my line manager who passed me to HR who then passed me to the Directors this went on for 2 weeks, I came in and my desk had been moved and I had an anxiety attack. I then spoke to my line manager and a Director that was there and the result was they made me sit there in tears. I didn't want anyone to know my past this was fresh start and even after bearing my all they still making me sit there. What can I do?

This may be sensitive and invasive, we don't need know all the details, but what we do need general idea of what's causing you to be unable to sit in any other arrangement, and are your bosses aware of it? And what country is that in.

This is not really a work issue, but more of a mental health issue.  You should seek therapy here, as there is a lot more going on than a desire for some privacy.

If you are signed off by the medical professional, will they notice the work not done?

While (as other answers mention) the longer term solution is to address the underlying causes of the anxiety and its' associated reaction. That sort of thing doesn't happen overnight and so it doesn't address the immediate situation.
You don't mention location but in the UK (and many other locations) if there is an associated medical diagnosis then (with the aid of your medical practitioner) you may be able seek a "reasonable adjustment" from your employer to address the situation in the meantime and something like seating arrangements might be something that can be accommodated. The UK would cover this under the Equality Act 2010, examples of some conditions that would be grounds for requesting an accommodation include:

•  mental health conditions with symptoms such as anxiety, low mood, panic attacks, phobias, or unshared perceptions; eating disorders; bipolar affective disorders; obsessive compulsive disorders; personality disorders; post traumatic stress disorder, and some self-harming behaviour;
• mental illnesses, such as depression and schizophrenia;

For more info see here
There's no guarantee they will provide the adjustment you want, as the law places certain limits on what is considered reasonable for a business to take on on when accommodating those covered by the Act. That said, it is worth looking in to.

But it still starts with recognizing that this is a medical problem and seeking diagnosis and advice. If an unreasonable reaction is strong enough to interfere with your life, and you can't manage it yourself, get assistance.

Address the underlying issue here and not just the seating situation.
If the change in seating has initiated a trigger reaction in you, then other everyday situations will as well.
Speak with your doctor/counsellor and do what you can to address your trigger points and work from there.
It sounds as though your employer has done what they can to help, but this for some reason didn't work out for you, so you're probably best served by seeking independent help.

Most companies seating policy is simple "you sit where we assign you a seat". They don't have much of a choice there, since everyone has seating preferences and trying to accommodate these would result in chaos and even more frustration (don't ask me how I know).
It is difficult for the company to make an exception: once word gets around, everyone will want an exception too. Hence most companies are fairly strict about it.
It is very unfortunate that this causes you undue stress. Your best cause of action would be to seek help from a medical professional. Maybe they can address your stress issue. If not, they can give you a note that you need specific seating accommodations. Almost all companies will make accommodations that are certified by a medical professional. In some legislations they are even legally required to do so, but its also the the right thing to do. The certification gives them an "objective" reason to make an exception to the policy.

This is definitely not true for people with mental health issues in the US https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/guidance/depression-ptsd-other-mental-health-conditions-workplace-your-legal-rights


What can i do?

That depends on what you are hoping to accomplish.
If you want your desk in a particular place, you can ask for it.
If you need help with your upset/anxiety/tears, seek professional mental health help.
